# Galaxy S2 keeps periodically showing "Refreshing SIM data" toast

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2

I have a rooted Samsung Galaxy S2 running the stock Samsung ROM (no custom ROMs ever). 
Of late, I notice that every few minutes, a toast pops up saying 'Refreshing SIM data'. If the screen had been blanked earlier, it reactivates, and this is annoying, especially at night. 
I don't know if this is relevant, but only recently I got 3G activated (Vodafone, Bangalore,India) and it didn't happen before.

Anyone seen this, and is there a workaround or fix?

**Update** - Have upgraded to 2.3.5 Gingerbread and with different kernels ([Ninphetamine](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1179814) and [DarkyROM SuperCore](http://www.darkyrom.com/community/index.php?threads/rom-cwm-sgs2-2-3-5-darkyrom2-xxki3-base.5710/)) but it makes no difference. I wonder if it's because of the service provider.

Comment: I found the same thing happen to my galaxyace after I activated 3g vodafone bangalore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a solution that works for Indian Vodafone 3G users at least.

Simply create a new access point with the same settings as the one provided (called Vodafone Connect), set it as default, and reboot.
I've not seen the popup appear again after that.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that the SIM contacts are corroded or bent slightly, so that the phone thinks it lost connection and then regained it? If this is the case, try cleaning the contacts with alcohol.

Comment: I checked the SIM, it looks pretty clean, but still took it out and replaced it. I've seen other users also report this problem across various fora but haven't found a solution so far.